# Grid design using percentages (33.333%) breaking in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, cross-browser

gots a problem here with percentages.

I’m working on a front end for an intranet database and have practically finished the job, BUT, I’ve found a rather stubborn bug.  This renders fine in firefox, but in chrome, I’m getting box size problems probably to do with how the two calculate percentages.

I can't post my screen grabs but here’s the fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/DeanActual/k317fpz5/

You'll see if you move the viewport around in chrome some of the small boxes get "stuck" alongside the large box.  Doesn’t matter if it’s with or without borders and I’ve tried messing around with percentages such as 33.329% which, again, seem to be taken on board by firefox but spurned by chrome.

I’ve read around a bit and it seems to be quite a well known problem that plagues many, but I haven't been able to find a fix.

Fiddle code below:

```
<div id="body">    
  <div class="block large"></div>
  <div class="block small"></div>
  <div class="block small"></div>
  <div class="block small"></div>
  <div class="block small"></div>
  <div class="block small"></div>
  <div class="block small"></div>
  <div class="block small"></div>
  <div class="block small"></div>
  <div class="block small"></div>
  <div class="block small"></div>
  <div class="block small"></div>
  <div class="block small"></div>    
</div>
```

CSS:

```
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.block:after{
    content:" ";
    display:block;
    margin-top: 100%;
}

.block{
    float:left;
    border:5px solid black;
}

.large{
    width:33.329%;
    background:pink;
}

.small{
    width:16.666%;
}

div .small:nth-of-type(3n+1) {
     background-color: blue;
}
div .small:nth-of-type(3n+2) {
     background-color: red;
}
div .small:nth-of-type(3n+3) {
     background-color: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For small divisions you should decrease width to 16.600% and for smaller sizes you can use media queries and make that width more smaller and make it to 16.500%. So, you can get desired result for both large and small screens and for every browser.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome renders it correctly. `float: left` means "as left as possible", when there is nothing (because of the height) to the left, the `div` is positioned at `left:0` of the container.
When you want to achieve your expected layout, make a container of width 33%, containing the big block and another container of width 66%, containing the small blocks.

Comment: Thanks @Pavel Gatnar, I can see how this would work but the small blocks have to be able to flow around the large block.  If I place them into a div at 66% they will be contained an be unable to fall underneath the large block.

Comment: @WadsMillenia first try with fixed sizes (e.g. h&w=200px, resp. 100px)